# how to 'fuzzy' match strings when merge two dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframe `df1` and `df2`.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame ({'Name': ['Adam Smith', 'Anne Kim', 'John Weber', 'Ian Ford'],
                     'Age': [43, 21, 55, 24]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'Name': ['adam Smith', 'Annie Kim', 'John  Weber', 'Ian Ford'],
                     'gender': ['M', 'F', 'M', 'M']})
```

I need to join these two dataframe with pandas.merge on the column `Name`. However, as you notice, there are some slight difference between column `Name` from the two dataframe. Let's assume they are the same person.  If I simply do:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='Name')
```

I only got a dataframe back with only one row, which is 'Ian Ford'.

Does anyone know how to merge these two dataframe ? I guess this is pretty common situation if we join two tables on a string column. I have absolutely no idea how to handle this. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am using `fuzzywuzzy` here

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process



df2['key']=df2.Name.apply(lambda x : [process.extract(x, df1.Name, limit=1)][0][0][0])

df2.merge(df1,left_on='key',right_on='Name')
Out[1238]: 
        Name_x gender         key  Age      Name_y
0   adam Smith      M  Adam Smith   43  Adam Smith
1    Annie Kim      F    Anne Kim   21    Anne Kim
2  John  Weber      M  John Weber   55  John Weber
3     Ian Ford      M    Ian Ford   24    Ian Ford
```

Comment: Thank you ! this is what I need.  what does 'process.extract(x, df1.Name, limit=1)][0][0][0]' do here?

Comment: @zesla getting the first matching Item , and that result is odd, it is tuple of tuple, that is why we need [0][0][0] here .. do not worry about it

Comment: a follow-u question,  for process.extract, there used to be a argument score_cutoff, which I think is pretty useful. It seems that it's not there anymore. Do you know how should I define the score cutoff? Thank you so much. @Wen

Comment: @zesla [score for found, score, matchrow in process.extract(x, df1.Name, limit=1)], you can find the score, that is why We need [0][0][0], cause the function return multiple result  :-)

Comment: What I mean was the argument score_cutoff  in the process.extract function. It used to be there.  I googled and found some of its usage. Basically if the score is less than the cutoff, it returns nan. However, when I check the function argument, it seems that it's not there any more....@Wen

Comment: @zesla I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055817/python-fuzzy-matching-fuzzywuzzy-keep-only-best-match, you can setting up your own limit score

Comment: thank you very much for the link.  I think it's soooo weird that there is no such argument anymore, isn't it?   Just don't understand why...   do we miss anything? @Wen

Comment: I figure it out. process.extractOne has score_cutoff, not process.extract... Sorry about the confusion. @Wen

Comment: So I think in this case,(or in general),  it's probably better to use process.extractOne and also set a score_cutoff, so that it does not always produce a match, if two strings are too different.., what do you think? @Wen

Comment: This is incredible and saved me hours of manual work. Thank you very much.

Comment: @campo yw :-) happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if fuzzy match is what you are looking for. Maybe make every name a proper name?

```
df1.Name = df1.Name.apply(lambda x: x.title())
df2.Name = df2.Name.apply(lambda x: x.title())

pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner', on='Name')
```

Comment: what about 'Anne' vs 'Annie', 'John Weber' vs 'John  Weber'?

Comment: How can you assume that Anne is the same as Annie?