# Python group similar records (strings) in dataset

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis, string-matching, fuzzywuzzy

I have an input table like this:

```
In [182]: data_set
Out[182]: 
       name             ID
0  stackoverflow       123      
1  stikoverflow        322      
2  stack, overflow     411      
3  internet.com        531      
4  internet            112      
5  football            001
```

And I want to group similar strings based on fuzzywuzzy. So after applying fuzzy matching, all strings with more than some similarity threshold (like > %90 similarity) would group together. So the desired output would be:

```
In [182]: output
Out[182]: 
       name             ID     group
0  stackoverflow       123       1
1  stikoverflow        322       1
2  stack, overflow     411       1
3  internet.com        531       2
4  internet            112       2
5  football            001       3
```

I was searching through different topics and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969383/fuzzy-string-matching-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41455093/searching-one-python-dataframe-dictionary-for-fuzzy-matches-in-another-datafra?rq=1) which are only name matching and not doing clustering. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32055817/python-fuzzy-matching-fuzzywuzzy-keep-only-best-match) one shows the best match only which it doesn't help me. This [page](https://nlpforhackers.io/recipe-text-clustering/) is also explaining about k-means clustering which the number of clusters needs to be set beforehand, which is not practical in this case.

UPDATE:

I figured out `process` method in `fuzzywuzzy` package would handle my problem to some extent. But this method only compares string to a list and not list to list:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

with open("data-set.txt", "r") as f:
     data = f.read().split("\n")
process.extract("stackoverflow",data, limit=3)
```

Output:

```
[('stackoverflow', 100), ('stack, overflow', 93), ('stikoverflow', 88)]
```

But still dont know how can I use it to cluster.

Comment: This is *not* a clustering problem. It's closer related to spelling correction. For an **unsupervised** approach, dog and fog are very close. Doggy and foggy are also close. But dog and doggy are much more different. So don't use anything unsupervised!

Comment: I believe at some point we could consider it as a clustering problem since we have a similarity function and the similar strings are grouped together based on some threshold, correct?

Comment: the example I gave is a counterexample for this hypothesis. You don't have a good enough similarity function. Use something supervised.

Comment: I guess any function I used, I would have some false positives anyhow. I'd like to apply it on millions of records. An end user will evaluate it at the end. I just wanna give them a group of similar records from which they select what they want. What similarity function you recommend?

Comment: None. There is none that I know that would work. People will likely suggest Levenshtein, but that one really won't work well. Just try it yourself.

Comment: So Fuzzywuzzy is based on Leveneshtein, right?

Answer (score -1):

This can be accomplished using `string-grouper`:

```py
    from string_grouper import group_similar_strings
    group_similar_strings(data_set['name'])
```

[string-grouper](https://github.com/Bergvca/string_grouper)